# is it possible to change the name of a file after it's been uploaded

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Is there any way for a php script to choose the name for a file after it's been uploaded by the user using an HTML form? I am wanting to allow users to upload an avatar for their account and would like it named with their userid instead of whatever the name of it is on their computer. I'm using a basic HTML upload form which only allows jpegs and png files with a 10MB file limit, similar to the file upload code give on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: basically, the upload goes to temp storage and it is up to you to handle it. As suggested below, you can rename it at that stage. Indeed, it is probably a bad idea from a security standpoint to allow the end-user to specify the name at all. For more info and various methods, google: "security exploit file upload php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the filename when using move_uploaded_file(), otherwise you can rename() the file.

Answer (score 2):

Put the desired filename in the second argument of [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I suppose I should have looked at how that function works before asking lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
$userid = 5; // say you fetch it from database
$ext = explode("\/",$_FILES["file"]["type"]); //extract the file extension
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$userid.$ext[1]);
```

**UPDATE:** 
I think you don't need to extract file extension.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$userid);
```